# Practicality of JavaScript templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine

Similar to this question; [When to use JavaScript template engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077016/when-to-use-javascript-template-engines) but not quite.

Is it practical to make full sites (e.g. skip static HTML and PHP processing and just send JavaScript with HTML templates for client side rendering) in client-side JavaScript with a template engine such as handlebars? Or, are template engines only useful when it comes to re-usable template sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have half of the the answer, which is re-use, but you can get that on the server-side.  To me the other half is as follows:

1. Allow front-end developers to handle all the interactive development in JS and HTML, almost without knowing JS for simple templating needs.
2. For web applications the UI rendering on the server slows or limits the interactions/experiences one can design, or at least limit performance.  Why does the server have to know and understand the User button clicks?  The browser is powerful enough to handle the button clicks.
3. It pairs nicely with REST services.  The browser knows how to request the data and determine the user context.
4. More complex web server side design.  State is a very complex thing to manage across clusters and nodes.  Not that you can't but why should you?  Especially as for most modern web applications (web 2.0 and all that jazz) the whole point is the browser doing more, handling button clicks, sorting data, etc.  Guess what all that is user state.  So the browser already has a lot.  So why distribute that state across a cluster of servers adding latency, dependencies, etc.  I have a no HTML in the application server policy.
5. Change control.  When you write PHP and embed HTML snips in everything things end up tightly coupled.  It reduces flexibility of use case changes.
6. Separation of concerns, forcefully.  Many developers are tempted to do business logic in the view.  Simple templates help reduce the likelihood of this.  One could easily construct an argument against all non-templating based approaches, JS or server-side but that is not the question at hand.
7. If you are going to build a mobile app you want and need services that avoid presentation markup.  So never generate HTML in the application server or else your app will only speak one language.  People might shout server side MVC will help, but not for off-line, different access patterns, etc.
8. There are some performance, device detection, 'dumb phone' reasons to generate html server-side, but then write it off of the services which your JS web app use.  Let that be the exception.  Even better write it in JS on the server-side and re-use the business functions and logic on both.

Answer (score 0):

I use a JavaScript template engine when I make one-page web-apps (with backbone.js for example).

In any other case, I would not use a JavaScript template engine.

The reason for this is, that if I create an application in anything other than JavaScript-only (PHP, Rails etc.), I like having the templates done on the server rather than at the client.