# How to create HTML for django objects after AJAX?

Tags: ajax, django

This must be pretty basic or Im just thinking it wrong. Please help.

In a template I query a few objects and display them as follows:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
 {{obj.attr1}}
 {{obj.attr2}}
{% endfor }}
```

Now, suppose I create another object at the server side and respond back the new object data with AJAX, for example this is the response:
:

```
{'attr1':some_attribute,
 'attr2':some_attribute'}
```

How do i append the new object to the for loop of objects?

Comment: Can you clarify or rephrase the question? I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Please see if its understandable now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building HTML with templates versus building it in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240026/building-html-with-templates-versus-building-it-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some html tags to your content like this:

```
<ul class="content">
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li>{{obj.attr1}}, {{obj.attr2}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

then use jQuery to append new object:

```
$('.content').append('<li>' + data.attr1 + ', '+ data.attr2 + '</li>');
```

`data` is the response object.