# UI design: templates for wizard driven app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templating

Greetings,

I have moderate experience design UIs that combine JS and HTML. Problem is that most of that technology I know is "old".

I poked around the web and I've seen really nice looking sites using (seemingly) libraries such as jQuery.

My boss just assigned me to build a prototype of an app dedicated to our field staff. I want to design something that is a) "sexy" b) can display on both handheld and lap/desktop (CSS) and c) wizard driven.

Something like this would be ideal...the user navigates to the home page and see the first "wizard"

```
Step 1)
a) install product AAA
b) install product BBB.
...check a) and Click NEXT

Step 1.a) "You chose `install product AAA`" 
a) troubleshooting
b) tech bulletins
...
```

I started playing with jQuery but I wonder if is there a templating app that I could use for that purpose?? Am I dreaming.......?

TIA,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines)
- [quick tip about templating with
  jquery on net.tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-jquery-templating/)
- [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) not a template engine
  but a collection of tools to enhance
  your app

However my opinion is to use javascript to only add interaction and not to present the data.