# jQuery Template Engine

Tags: jquery, templates

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines), what are jQuery template engines?

What are the benefits and advantages of using them?

Comment: Look through the questions on the bottom-right-hand-corner of this page. They are pretty relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

> Client-side templates enable jQuery
>   developers to easily generate and
>   render HTML UI on the client. 
>   Templates support a simple syntax that
>   enables either developers or designers
>   to declaratively specify the HTML they
>   want to generate.  Developers can then
>   programmatically invoke the templates
>   on the client, and pass JavaScript
>   objects to them to make the content
>   rendered completely data driven. 
>   These JavaScript objects can
>   optionally be based on data retrieved
>   from a server.

The benefits of using them is that you can seperate your logic (Main UI and controls) and **code reuse**.  The latter being the bigger advantage IMO.  As for disadvantages, well... maybe learning curve?  Or excess free-time?  Both are inherent disadvantages (if you don't like to be productive)