# what is the best way to deal with ajax and generating html that is beyond prototyping

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For my project I am starting to get alot of embeded html in my javascript as a result of ajax calls. I want to move them out of there. What is the best practice for this? I was thinking have the elements as a div in the page with display:none then deal with when the javascript needs it.

But If I use this method I need to replace certain string with the data return from my ajax call, any advise on that?

Thanks

Comment: what i usually do is add formatting definitions in the returned json data. this way the correct html is automatically generated

Comment: @Ibu, JSON is for data transport, adding formatting to it kind of makes it like HTML, so if you are doing this why aren't you using HTML directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a templating framework such as [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). Here's a [blog post](http://expansive-derivation.ossreleasefeed.com/2010/10/jquery-templates-beyond-the-basics-the-why-and-how/) about it.

The are also other engines you might take a look at:

- [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)
- [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- [JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

Comment: I like MicroTemplating best, but use the jQuote2 version of it, not the original. http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/

Comment: If starting with templates, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines