# What to use in place of jQuery template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsrender

Since jQuery template will become obsolete in the future, what is a good alternative to use in its place? Is JsRender mature enough to be incorporated into an enterprise level application? What are the other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions for current jQuery template solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973227/suggestions-for-current-jquery-template-solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my preferences

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) is most straightforward solution since it's simply embedded javascript. I use it almost all my templating needs except for when I'm actually building a complete web app

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is sophisticated. It's better to use if you're going to be writing a lot of template code that depends on a good amount of logic, because that's where simply embedding javascript can lead to messy code. It's opinionated to be mostly logic-less, and while it may be counter-intuitive to not have any display logic in your view, it's cleaner and is a structure that pays off more and more as your app grows.